# Docker swarm mode mesh routing is not working at all

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-engine

I have docker swarm mode set up with 3 ubuntu 16.04 machines with vagrant. I don't think mesh routing is working at all.

If I set up a service like

`docker service create --name helloworld --replicas 1 -p 8888:80 nginx`

I can see my service with

```
docker service ls
ID            NAME        REPLICAS  IMAGE  COMMAND
evbp2spkjn50  helloworld  1/1       nginx
```

I can curl to the ip of the machine that the actual container is running on:

```
curl 172.28.100.101:8888
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
....
```

But if I go to any other machine in the swarm, I am not routed properly:

```
curl 172.28.100.102:8888
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 172.28.100.102 port 8888: Connection refused
```

Now, if I scale the service such that a container is running on all of the machines like this:

```
docker service scale helloworld=3
helloworld scaled to 3
```

All of a sudden I can curl to it.

```
curl 172.28.100.102:8888
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome to nginx!</title>
....
```

All ports are open between these machines (they are set up with `vm.network :private_network, :ip => "172.28.100.10X", :netmask => "255.255.0.0"` in vagrant).

I have tried this with a dedicated network with no change.

```
docker --version
Docker version 1.12.1, build 23cf638
```

Answer (score 1):

There's an [open issue on github](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/25325) that's likely related to what you're seeing. I think there are still some edge cases where the mesh routing isn't working right, and have seen this in some of my own tests with 1.12.

Answer (score 0):

I switched from Ubuntu to RancherOS and the bad behavior disappeared. I'm guessing there is something about the kernel config that isn't right.